# Flask form not validating properly using flask-wtf

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

here is my controller code

```
@auth.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signin():
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    # return form.email.data
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return form.email.data
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user and check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            session['user_id'] = user.id
            flash('Welcome %s' % user.name)
            return redirect(url_for('auth.home'))
        else:
            return "invalid username and password"
    return "Signin form"
```

code for form

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    email    = TextField('Email Address', [
                Required(message='Forgot your email address?')])
    password = PasswordField('Password', [
                Required(message='Must provide a password. ;-)')])
```

I am checking using following curl request

```
curl -i localhost:9000/auth/login/ --data "email=a@b.com&password=b" -X POST
```

the form is getting the data but fails at validate_on_submit(). What is the reason for the same. Also if it is because of csrf tokens please tell me how to disable it as i am just getting started with the same.

I think it is important that i disabled CSRF in config using

```
CSRF_ENABLED     = False
```

and then loaded config using
    app.config.from_object('config')

but it still does not seem to be working. One more thing worth mentioning is that this is for a rest api

Comment: What validation errors are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved the issue. WTF-Form csrf does not get disabled by `CSRF_ENABLED`. To disable it globally, the following should be added to the config

`WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False`